# Java9 Causes ClassNotFoundException for Class in Packaged Library

Tags: java, java-9

I have the following problem with Java9 using the below simple application.
The application has the main class **Main**:

```
package app;

import lib.Greeting;

public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( new Greeting().hello() );
    }
}
```

The class **Greeting** is the following and packaged in the separate jar library **lib.jar**:

```
package lib;

public class Greeting {
    public String hello() {
        return "Hi from Greeting lib!";
    }
}
```

The application Main and lib.jar are packaged by Eclipse to the app.jar library with the manifest file as follows:

```
**Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ lib.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: app.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader**
```

When I run this application with Java8, it works as expected:

```
C:\java\J9Test\libs>java -jar app.jar
Hi from Greeting lib!
```

When I run this application with Java9, the following exception is raised:

```
C:\orawork\java\J9Test\libs>d:\jdk1.9\bin\java.exe -jar app.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lib/Greeting
        at app.Main.main(Main.java:7)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lib.Greeting
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 6 more
```

How to resolve this problem and run this simple app successfully with both Java8 and 9?

Comment: check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606502/how-to-add-a-java-9-module-via-manifest-mf

Comment: Please maintain the classpath for java( Java_Home)

Comment: While executing the jar with Java9 make sure that the jar is found either in the classpath or the modulepath. Adding `--module-path <path to lib.jar>` to the command shall solve it.

Comment: thank you. how can I use --module-path <path to lib.jar> if this lib.jar is contained in the app.jar of the application?

Comment: @michael Could you share the app.jar structure. I didn't get the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Eclipse-specific technology to [create executable jars](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-37.htm?cp=1_3_1_4) by [including dependencies as nested jars](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-export-runnable-jar.htm?cp=1_4_9_8) (see "Library handling") is not fully adjusted to Java 9 as of Eclipse Oxygen.1a.

According to [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515921#c19) this has been fixed in Oxygen.2 which will be released on 2017-12-20 (release candidates exist).

Comment: Right. Thank you, Stephen! I already discovered this and decided to include extracted classes to the target app jar instead of lib jars.